How to download files using REST API and process them with Nextflow
I need to use REST API to download files in JSON. Then, I will run another process to update these files, for example, modify these files and submit these files to another database, etc. However, my code returns nothing. I learned from the first script and I am aware that Nextflow syntax looks like Groovy.
Has anyone experienced with Nextflow to help me?
params.input = "work/4b/f05e21cb1af45528bf4e66e45c7680/MD0001.json"
input_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.input)

params.modelId = "MD0001"

process downloadModel {
        input:
        def modelId

        output:
        path 'model_*'

        script:
        def idx = String.format("%06d", task.index)

        """
        wget -O '${params.modelId}'.json https://www.myservice.com/download/'${params.modelId}'?format=json
        printf ${idx}
        """
}
process handleSubmission {
        input:
        path file

        output:
        stdout

        script:
        //def idx = String.format("%06d", hash)

        """
        printf '${hash}\n'
        cat '${file}' | jq
        """
}

workflow  {
        downloadModel
        handleSubmission(input_ch)
        handleSubmission.out.view()
}


Few things: show output if you want help, it is vital for others to see what is(n't) happening.
Don't stage files from your work folder, this is your workflow cache and should only be used to resume runs or for introspection when errors occur.
It looks like you aren't calling downloadModel because there are no parentheses downloadModel instead of downloadModel()

Apart from what's been pointed out in user Pallies answer, I think you need to generally make yourself familiar with the concept of channels in nextflow. Your downloadModel process defines an input, which is basically never used, instead you are trying to get the model id from a parameter, which is no good solution. What you want to do with nextflow, is to write your processes in a way, that they use variable information from the input defined and use those global parameters for variables, that would stay constant for each single function call within the workflow. In your case an example for a parameter could be params.url for the constant part of your REST-API url.
A solution for such a channel might look like this (not tested):
Write all your IDs in a textfile (models_to_download.txt) as list (newline separated)
// create a channel from a textfile. use splitText operator to read the contents of the file
// and split each single line into single entries in your channel
model_ids = Channel.fromPath("models_to_download.txt").splitText()
downloadModel(model_ids)

Another minor problem with your process downloadModel is, that the output specification will not work unless your model-names actually all start with model_, which seems to be not the case for the single example file you've shown.
You can be very explicit about the expected output e.g. directly specifying the name without wildcards if you anyway name the file accordingly in your script:
process downloadModel {
maxForks 1
input:
     val modelId
output:
     val "${modelId}.json"
script:
"""
wget -O "${modelId}.json" "${params.url}/${modelId}?format=json"
"""
}

IMPORTANT NOTE: make sure the server you are pulling your files from allows for rapid parallel access via this API, because nextflow will spawn as many parallel processes as your machine has CPUs (or even hundreds if you use cloud or HPC clusters). I would strongly suggest to use the maxForks directive to limit the number of parallel downloadModel processes.
As you are dealing with internet resources I would also suggest you use errorStrategy retry in combination with maxRetries and the -resume-flag for restarting in case your workflow still crashes. If your downstream process tolerates some incompleteness, you can even use a dynamic errorStrategy like this
// retry twice and then ignore additional errors 
// so the rest of the workflow may continue after failures
errorStrategy { task.attempt < 3 ? 'retry' : 'ignore' }

